# JavaFX combobox item selected displayed in list box

Tags: javafx

I'm having some trouble with transferring whats selected in a combobox and display in a list box. I'm not sure exactly how to do it. I have tried many different ways with no luck. All examples given on the internet refer to scene builder. I cannot create this with scene builder. Could someone please give me a hand and help me. I'm not sure if it should be an action event or a listener to do what I want. Please forgive the newb question. Thank you!!

```
package application;

import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Pane pane = new Pane();

    double beverageArray[] = { 1.95, 1.50, 1.25, 2.95, 2.50, 1.50 };
    double appetizerArray[] = { 5.95, 6.95, 8.95, 8.95, 10.95, 12.95, 6.95 };
    double mainCourseArray[] = { 15.95, 13.95, 13.95, 11.95, 19.95, 20.95, 18.95, 13.95, 14.95 };
    double desertArray[] = { 5.95, 3.95, 5.95, 4.95, 5.95 };
    String[] beverages = { "Soda", "Tea", "Coffee", "Mineral Water", "Juice", "Milk" };
    double totalCost = 0;

    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    pane.setHgap(5.5);
    pane.setVgap(5.5);

    ComboBox<String> beverageComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(beverages);
    beverageComboBox.getItems().addAll(items);

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // final ComboBox<String> beverageComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    // beverageComboBox.getItems().addAll("Soda", "Tea", "Coffee", "Mineral
    // Water", "Juice",
    // "Milk");
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    final ComboBox<String> appetizerComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    appetizerComboBox.getItems().addAll("Buffalo Wings", "Buffalo Fingers", "Potato Skins", "Nachos",
            "Mushroom Caps", "Shrimp Cocktail");

    final ComboBox<String> maincourseComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    maincourseComboBox.getItems().addAll("Seafood Alfredo", "Chicken Alfredo", "Chicken Picatta", "Turkey Club",
            "Lobster Pie", "Prime Rib", "Shrimp Scampi", "Turkey Dinner", "Stuffed Chicken");

    final ComboBox<String> dessertComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    dessertComboBox.getItems().addAll("Apple Pie", "Sundae", "Carrot Cake", "Mud Pie", "Apple Crisp");
    /*
     * beverageComboBox.setValue("Soda"); appetizerComboB(ox.setValue(
     * "Buffalo Wings"); maincourseComboBox.setValue("Seafood Alfredo");
     * dessertComboBox.setValue("Apple Pie");
     */

    Image image = new Image("fd.jpg");
    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label tit = new Label("John's");
    tit.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.BOLD, 32));
    pane.add(tit, 1, 0);
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label wi = new Label("Waiter Information");
    wi.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    pane.add(wi, 0, 5);

    Label tn = new Label("Table Number:");
    pane.add(tn, 0, 6);
    TextField tnf = new TextField();
    pane.add(tnf, 1, 6);

    Label wn = new Label("Waiter's Name:");
    pane.add(wn, 0, 7);
    TextField twn = new TextField();
    pane.add(twn, 1, 7);

    // exception handling HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label mi = new Label("Menu Items");
    mi.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    pane.add(mi, 0, 10);

    Label b = new Label("Beverage:");
    pane.add(b, 0, 11);
    pane.add(beverageComboBox, 1, 11);

    Label a = new Label("Appetizer:");
    pane.add(a, 0, 12);
    pane.add(appetizerComboBox, 1, 12);

    Label mc = new Label("Main Course:");
    pane.add(mc, 0, 13);
    pane.add(maincourseComboBox, 1, 13);

    Label d = new Label("Dessert:");
    pane.add(d, 0, 14);
    pane.add(dessertComboBox, 1, 14);
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label bi = new Label("Bill");
    bi.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    pane.add(bi, 0, 17);

    Label st = new Label("Subtotal:");
    pane.add(st, 0, 18);
    TextField tst = new TextField();
    pane.add(tst, 1, 18);

    Label t = new Label("Tax:");
    pane.add(t, 0, 19);
    TextField tt = new TextField();
    pane.add(tt, 1, 19);

    Label to = new Label("Total:");
    pane.add(to, 0, 20);
    TextField tto = new TextField();
    pane.add(tto, 1, 20);
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label w = new Label("Waiter:");
    pane.add(w, 0, 23);
    TextField tw = new TextField();
    pane.add(tw, 1, 23);

    Label tn2 = new Label("Table Num:");
    pane.add(tn2, 0, 24);
    TextField ttn = new TextField();
    pane.add(ttn, 1, 24);
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Button btn = new Button("    Clear Bill    ");
    pane.add(btn, 1, 30);
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Label io = new Label("Items Ordered");
    io.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    pane.add(io, 2, 3);
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label bo = new Label("Beverage Ordered");
    pane.add(bo, 2, 5);

    ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();

    ObservableList<String> items1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(beverages);
    // list.setItems(items1);
    beverageComboBox.getItems().addAll(items1);

    pane.add(list, 3, 5);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list, 5);

    beverageComboBox.setOnAction(e -> setDisplay(items.indexOf(beverageComboBox.getValue())));

    /*
     * list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( ov -> {
     * pane.getChildren().clear(); for (Integer i:
     * list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()){
     * pane.getChildren().add(beverages[i]); } });
     */
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label ao = new Label("Appetizer Ordered");
    pane.add(ao, 2, 10);

    ListView<String> list2 = new ListView<>();

    ObservableList<String> items2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list2.setItems(items2);

    pane.add(list2, 3, 10);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list2, 5);
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label mco = new Label("Main Course Ordered");
    pane.add(mco, 2, 15);

    ListView<String> list3 = new ListView<>();

    ObservableList<String> items3 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list3.setItems(items3);

    pane.add(list3, 3, 15);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list3, 5);
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Label od = new Label("Dessert Ordered");
    pane.add(od, 2, 20);

    ListView<String> list4 = new ListView<>();

    ObservableList<String> items4 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list4.setItems(items4);

    pane.add(list4, 3, 20);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list4, 5);

    // Create a new scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 800);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Restaurant Bill Calculator");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

 }  
 }
```

Comment: Insteading of posting the code of your whole program, please replace it with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This makes it much easier to understand your issue and help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
beverageComboBox.setOnAction((e) -> {
    list.getItems().add(beverageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error. list is underlined--list cannot be resolved.

Comment: NavaneethThank you that works perfectly!!! I tried that so many times I just didn't have it in the right area. THANK YOU !!!!

Comment: If I wanted to deselect an item from the LISTBOX--ie if an item is clicked in the listbox it should be removed from the listbox how would I do that??

Comment: Added a button `Button removeButton = new Button("Remove");` and do `removeButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
            list.getItems().remove(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        });`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a button??

Comment: I got it thank you i changed it around  little for a mouse click action

Comment: is there a reason that when I select an item i cannot select the same item again and add it?? ie--soda soda tea.... I have to select soda tea soda??

Comment: When u try to select the same item which has been previously selected, combo box doesn't fire action event. Since your adding items to the list view in combo box's action handler, it is not adding item to list view for same selection.

Comment: is there a way to fix that??